# Decrypting The Password From Cipher Text To Plain Text

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string EPass = Helper.ComputeHash(txtPassword.Text, "SHA512", null);
    lblmsg.Text = EPass; //Encrypting The Plain Text To Cipher Text 
}
protected void btnAuthenticate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool flag = Helper.VerifyHash(txtPassword.Text, "SHA512", lblmsg.Text);
    if (flag == true) 
    {
        Label1.Text = "You are the correct user";       
    }
}
```

What method can I use in order to decrypt the Cipher text To plain Text and display the Plain Text into the Label. Thanks.

Comment: you are using a hash function, not an algorithm, u cannot decrypt a hash as like algos! so no, you cannot decrypt a hashed text to plain text!

Comment: Thanks @AppDeveloper for reply, any simple method can recommend to me from decrypt the Cipher text To plain Text. Thanks

Comment: well, u cant say decrypting, but cracking is possible!

Comment: This should be dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269101/c-sharp-reading-back-encrypted-passwords (and many other "how to reverse one way hash") question. It is very unlikly for one to have [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) for [SHA512](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) due to length of the digest.

Comment: Because this assignment is require me to display out the password to those users are forgot their password.

Comment: What you are doing is making a one-way hash of a password. This cannot be undone (unless you rainbow attack, look it up). You should also not be showing a person's password if they forget it. You should be giving them a new one, and throwing away the one they forgot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot decrypt the one way hashed password. Instead, you want to compare two hashed passwords.

```
protected void btnAuthenticate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string EPass = Helper.ComputeHash(txtPassword.Text, "SHA512", null);
    if (EPass == lblmsg.Text) 
    {
        Label1.Text = "You are the correct user";       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to make a login system, the way to do it is to compare encrypted text with the encrypted password. e.g.

```
string userEntry = Helper.ComputeHash(txtPassword.Text, "SHA512", null);


if (EPass == encrptedPassword) {
    Label1.Text "Success!";
}
```

That's how I go about doing it in PHP.